# ProxySQL SSL backend configuration from the config file

Tags: mysql, proxysql

Using proxysql 2.0.8 (docker severalnines/proxysql:2.0.8) and I was struggling to configure the SSL for backend servers (hosted as managed cloud instances).

At the end - it works while issueing following SQL statements in the admin interface:

```
UPDATE mysql_servers SET use_ssl=1;
LOAD MYSQL SERVERS TO RUNTIME;
```

Is there a way to configure the `use_ssl`parameter using the `/etc/proxysql.cfg` file?

Answer (score 0):

seem following configuration works  `use_ssl = 1` for mysql_servers

```
mysql_servers =
(

 {
  address = "mydbhost.mariadb.database.azure.com"
  port = 3306
  hostgroup = 0
  max_connections = 20
  use_ssl = 1
 }


)
```